# Magento 1.7.0.2 Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on a non-object in

Tags: magento, upgrade, categories, fatal-error

I just upgraded a Magento installation from 1.4.1.0 to 1.7.0.2. Now i have an error when trying to edit a category.

The error says:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on a non-object in /home/.../domains/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php on line 137
```

I found some topics on the forums about the same issue, but none had a solution. Could't find a solution here neither.

When i compare Attributes.php from the old version with the new version the only difference is this code block (lines 132 to 145):

```
    if ($this->getCategory()->getLevel() == 1) {
        $fieldset->removeField('custom_use_parent_settings');
    } else {
        if ($this->getCategory()->getCustomUseParentSettings()) {
            foreach ($this->getCategory()->getDesignAttributes() as $attribute) {
                if ($element = $form->getElement($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    $element->setDisabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($element = $form->getElement('custom_use_parent_settings')) {
            $element->setData('onchange', 'onCustomUseParentChanged(this)');
        }
    }
```

If i comment out this whole block everything seems to work fine. But is there a better fix? I actually don't get the purpose of this code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means

```
 $attribute->getAttributeCode(); // referring to invalid attribute ( object )
```

There is an attribute assigned to the categories in the old Database and you didn't migrate this

Find the old attribute assigned to catalog_category entity ( assumed be id 3 in 1.7 installation ) and also from the new Database after migration

```
SELECT *
FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE `entity_type_id` = '3'
```

Then compare the result from the old and the new Database

Comment: Thanks, i get the problem now. But what do you mean with "you didn't migrate this" i just upgraded my Magento installation. It should apply all db changes like this as wel right? I found the attribute_code which exsists in the old but not in the new db. It's, "custom_design_apply". Should i add this manually then?

Comment: Adding the complete row of "custom_design_apply" fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The attributes should be upgraded also when you upgrade the version, but what happen is it didn;t upgraded. so you need to do this manually :) good that you fix it.

Comment: These problems usually come about by not upgrading < 1.4.2.0 versions of Magento to 1.4.2.0 before proceeding upwards. Lot of database changes there. 1.6.2.0 is the next layer of heartburn.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($element = $form->getElement($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
    $element->setDisabled(true);    
}
```

replace to

```
if ($element = $form->getElement($attribute)) {
    $element->setDisabled(true);                           
}
```